# Inserts about 30 times MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

This php is supposed to insert into "d2" based on if that day is selected in "d1". It inserts about 30 times for each row in "d1". I use While all the time and never run into this problem, any idea why this would happen?

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection, 'SELECT * FROM '.$SETTINGS["d1"]);     
while($query_array = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){   
    $connection_main = mysqli_connect($SETTINGS["hostname"], $SETTINGS["mysql_user"], $SETTINGS["mysql_pass"], 'u_db_main_'.$query_array['id']);
    $dayofweek = strtolower(date('l'));
    $query2 = mysqli_query($connection_main, 'SELECT * FROM '.$SETTINGS_MAIN["d1"].' WHERE '.$dayofweek.' ="1"');
  while($query2_array = mysqli_fetch_array($query2)){   
       mysqli_query($connection_main, "INSERT INTO ".$SETTINGS_MAIN["d2"]." (c1) VALUE ('".$query2_array['data_1']."')");
       $id = mysqli_insert_id($connection_main);
       calc_function($id);
  }
}
```

The function calc_function has NO INSERTS in it but does use a global to get the same variables, could that be recalling the insert?

```
function calc_function($id){
   global $connection_main;
   global $SETTINGS_MAIN;
   //rest of function below
```

I have been working at this for a week and tested everything! Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why did you put `mysqli_connect`  inside of the `while`? Do `$connection_main` and `$connection` connect to different DB? Where is the rest of the `calc_function`?

Comment: `$connection_main` has a variable that is used from the initial while `'u_db_main_'.$query_array['id']`. The rest of the `calc_function` has nothing really to do with this problem and has no inserts in it.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to use the same connection resource to both fatch and insert. As soon as you run another query on that connection you will lose the previous results. Use [mysqli_fetch_all()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_all.asp) to get all of the results from $query2, then itterate the array and run the insert query.